# ImportError: cannot import name 'zoneinfo' from 'backports' (unknown location)

Tags: python, django, apache, backport

I am trying to deploy my Django model on an Apache2 server and it is running well on 'ip':8000. But when i am trying to run without 8000 port after completing all prerequisites i am getting this error

```
[Thu Jul 07 10:18:36.178228 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 368483:tid 139647379601152] [remote 106.79.194.125:58245]   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
[Thu Jul 07 10:18:36.178240 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 368483:tid 139647379601152] [remote 106.79.194.125:58245]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[Thu Jul 07 10:18:36.178247 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 368483:tid 139647379601152] [remote 106.79.194.125:58245]   File "/root/novo-ai-api-main/backend/dj/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 20, in <module>
[Thu Jul 07 10:18:36.178253 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 368483:tid 139647379601152] [remote 106.79.194.125:58245]     from django.db.backends.base.base import BaseDatabaseWrapper, timezone_constructor
[Thu Jul 07 10:18:36.178260 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 368483:tid 139647379601152] [remote 106.79.194.125:58245]   File "/root/novo-ai-api-main/backend/dj/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 12, in <module>
[Thu Jul 07 10:18:36.178277 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 368483:tid 139647379601152] [remote 106.79.194.125:58245]     from backports import zoneinfo
[Thu Jul 07 10:18:36.178308 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 368483:tid 139647379601152] [remote 106.79.194.125:58245] ImportError: cannot import name 'zoneinfo' from 'backports' (unknown location)
```

These are my all working files

### 000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        #ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /root/novo-ai-api-main


        ErrorLog /root/novo-ai-api-main/error.log
        CustomLog /root/novo-ai-api-main/access.log combine


        <Directory /root/novo-ai-api-main/backend/server/server>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                         Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>
        Alias /static /root/novo-ai-api-main/static
        <Directory /root/novo-ai-api-main/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>


        WSGIScriptAlias / /root/novo-ai-api-main/backend/server/server/wsgi.py
        WSGIDaemonProcess django_app python-path=/root/novo-ai-api-main/backend/server  python-home=/root/novo-ai-api-main/backend/dj/
        WSGIProcessGroup django_app

</VirtualHost>
```

### apache2.conf

**apache2.conf**

```
ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"
Timeout 300
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

#KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
#same client on the same connection.
KeepAliveTimeout 5

#These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

LogLevel warn

#Sets the default security model of the Apache2 HTTPD server. It does

<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>


#AccessFileName .htaccess

#<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
#Require all denied
#</FilesMatch>


IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf


IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

#vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

I installed mod_wsgi correctly for Python 3.8.10

**#wsgi.py**

```
 import os, sys
 import site
 site.addsitedir('/root/novo-ai-api-main/backend/dj/lib/python3.8/site-packages')
 from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
 os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'server.settings')
 application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Also I have given permissions to all the working files but nothing happened

```
#### 
    drwx--x--x  9 root     root       4096 Jun 16 22:05 .
    drwxr-xr-x 19 root     root       4096 Jun 14 14:05 ..
    drwxr-xr-x  3 root     root       4096 Jun 13 23:38 .local
    drwxrwxr-x  8 root     root       4096 Jun 16 01:24 mod_wsgi-4.9.2
    drwxr-xr-x  5 www-data www-data   4096 Jun 14 23:53 novo-ai-api-main <-(project)
    drwxr-xr-x 5 www-data www-data     4096 Jun 14 23:14 backend
    drw-r--r-- 8 www-data www-data     4096 Jun 14 00:33 static
    drwxr-xr-x 6 www-data www-data 4096 Jun 14 00:16 dj <- (venv) ####
```

What can I try next?

Answer (score 2):

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'backports'
I solved this error by first removing the package backports.zoneinfo from my project
and then re-install by typing
pip install backports.zoneinfo[tzdata]

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have solved this issue by giving permissions to all files and directories in my Django project. Using this command

```
find /root/novo-ai-api-main -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

It solved my many errors related to modules. If you are new to Apache deployment make sure you give right permissions to all files in directories.